# Is there any way to use osascript to run AppleScripts from an ssh session using a MacPorts installation of OpenSSH?

Tags: macos, applescript, ssh, macports, open-source

I'm running macOS 13.6.5, and have installed OpenSSH via MacPorts since I want to be running the latest version of OpenSSH. However, one downside to using a MacPorts installation of OpenSSH is that each ssh session is apparently not running in the right context to be able to interact with the window server, and therefore trying to use `osascript` to run AppleScripts that interact with running applications will all fail with an error `Application isn’t running. (-600)`.

Is there any way to be able to use MacPorts OpenSSH and still use `osascript` to run AppleScripts that interact with running applications?

Comment: Are you sure this works with native ssh?

Comment: @bmike Yes, I just tested it out. macOS's built in OpenSSH server runs ssh sessions under a process named `sshd-keygen-wrapper` which can send Apple events to other applications running as the same user.

Comment: What does replacing the Apple-shipped `ssh` gain you?

Comment: @MarcWilson Better security. Up-to-date OpenSSH means all known exploitable bugs have been patched. And just earlier today a botnet tried to gain access to my computer via ssh, possibly because it recognized that the older built-in release of OpenSSH that I had switched to was exploitable.